# How to load .mat file properly

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm trying to load a .mat file with this the code:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
matFile = loadmat('myFile.mat')

print(matFile)
```

[image]

But when I try to access to data with

```
matVar = matFile['Walking']
```

I get an array of void320 (1,1). How can I read properly the data? How can I access to all the subsets / variables inside the file?

Comment: In the MATLAB workspace this was some sort of `struct` and/or `cell`, not just one `matrix`.  Look at the shape and dtype.  `matVar.dtype` should show the 5 fields see at the bottom of the image.  If so `matVar['trunk']` would be one of those fields, probably a (1,1) array.  It's hard to read the nesting of arrays, but at some level you'll also need to index with 'acc' or 'gyr'.  e.g. `matVar['trunk']['acc']` might work, or you need some further indexing, e.g. `matVar['trunk'][0,0]['acc']`.

Comment: To put it another way, the is one variable in the file, which you found.  But it's a complicated MATLAB object, and the mapping from MATLAB to `numpy` isn't trivial. It will require some mix of `field` access and data element access.  We can't copy-n-paste anything from the image, so can't demonstrate any of that.

Comment: You are right! It's a complicated matlab structure which I no longer trace back to. I tried to copy the whole structure in the answer, but it was too long for this forum. And I know that figure is not so easy to understand. Is there any way to give you access to the data? Thank you anyway!